# lxml RelaxNG validation gives inexact results

Tags: python, lxml, relaxng

I'm using python 2.7 and lxml to validate a large xml file with RelaxNG. When the xml does not validate correctly I'm getting inexact result as to the location and nature of the problem. Usually it just says: "Element ElementName failed to validate content" - where ElementName is just the name of the top most element.

When I use the same xml and same relaxng files with Java I'm getting the exact line number where the error is.
Here is the code I'm using:

```
from lxml import etree  as ET
def ValidateXMLWithRNG(rng_file, xml_file):
    isXMLValid = False
    try:
        doc = ET.ElementTree()               
        doc.parse(xml_file)
        relaxng = ET.RelaxNG(file=rng_file)
        isXMLValid = relaxng.assert_(doc)
    except BaseException as ex:
        log = relaxng.error_log
        print log.last_error
    return isXMLValid
```

Is there a way to get more exact results from lxml and RelaxNG?

Comment: Are you sure the line number is not provided? When I try to validate an invalid XML file, I get error messages like this one: `test.xml:84:0:ERROR:RELAXNGV:RELAXNG_ERR_CONTENTVALID: Element article failed to validate content`. The line number is 84.

Comment: How large is the XML file? See https://github.com/lxml/lxml/issues/16 and https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=325533.

Comment: @mzjn: I'm getting a line number but the are nowhere near the actual line that caused the problem. Usually it's the line of the main element. As for the file size: it a few 1000's lines but not near the 65k limit.